How does the letter/number coding work for plugable screw terminals?
I am looking at all types of pluggable screw terminals on aliexpress. But I cannot figure out how the numbering system work.
To list a few
2EDGA  PCB THT straight angle male connector 7.62mm
15EDGA
15EDG  male THT connector to be soldered on PCB 3.81mm
KF2EDGKR  (wire 2 wire in 5.08mm pitch)
Kf2edgv   straight PCB THT socket 3.81mm
I don't know:

what the prefix KF means
how the pitches are noted. 2.54, 3.5mm, 3.81mm, 5.08mm and 7.62mm.
what the difference between 15 and 2 is and what more numbers there are
how I can see whether the thing must be soldered or is supposed to accept a wire
if it is straight or right angle

I think that the letter V indicates that it accepts a wire. But I really don't know.
Can somebody explain this to me or point me at an explanation?
EDIT: I learned that KF likely stands for 'Kwong Fung Group' and EDG is used by 'Degson Electronics'

The numbering system of what brand? Aliexpress is just a middle man junk trader, not a junk manufacturer. And there is no such thing as standard part names. Please link the datasheet.

The difference between 15 and 2 is 13. No but seriously, there is no grand scheme for naming connectors. Not within manufacturers and not between them

"I learned that KF likely stands for 'Kwong Fung Group' " Oh? https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22Kwong+Fung+Group%22+connectors returns zero results. There is a 'Kwong Fung Group' food company, but I doubt they make connectors. What is your source?

Each company makes up its own part numbering system, and it tends to be very inconsistent within a company, let alone among various companies. Some use significant part numbers (the letters and digits mean something to them), others use meaningless sequential numbers (e.g., TE and Molex), and some even use one of each (e.g., Phoenix Contact). We an only guess at what a given company means with one of its part numbers.

what the prefix KF means

It's a code for the name of the company: Cixi Kefa Electronics

how the pitches are noted. 2.54, 3.5mm, 3.81mm, 5.08mm and 7.62mm.

It totally depends on the manufacturer. Phoenix Contact does include the pitch in the part number (e.g. PT1.5/2-3.5-H for a 3.5 mm PCB terminal block). TE doesn't (e.g. 284391-3 for a 3.5 mm PCB terminal block).

what the difference between 15 and 2 is and what more numbers there are

It depends on the brand.
For example, in KF2EDGKR, the 2 is because, to Cixi Kefa Electronics, KF2 means a PCB terminal block with screw terminals.
And in JL15EDGA, the 15 is because , to JLIN, the JL15 means male right-angle PCB header.
Note how two different companies, Cixi Kefa and JLIN, use two different part numbering systems.

how I can see whether the thing must be soldered or is supposed to accept a wire

From the spec sheet, which you get access to if you buy electronic components from reputable vendors of electronic components: Digikey, LCSC, RS, Mouser...

if it is straight or right angle

Again, from the spec sheet.

Actually Phoenix are quite confusing since they have two part numbers for every part: one which makes some sense and contains pitch etc, and one which is just a "magic number" with no meaning at all.

Phoenix contact's datasheet quality is usually far, far below the products they are describing.
